# Correct way to forward traffic in nginx to node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, forwarding

I want to forward all traffic to a certain URL in nginx to node.js. I'm still new to node.js and I'm wondering if I should be using some kind of CGI service (like PHP) or if I should setup a node.js server (like nginx -> apache) and forward all traffic through nginx to that server like below:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
```

This is only a single page which needs to run a node.js script. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx reverse proxy (aka proxy_pass) doesn't support keep-alive.
But it's possible to establish keep-alive connection for FastCGI using a 3rd party module, Maxim Dounin's Upstream Keepalive module.

By the way, Node.js is yet stable to run without any reverse proxy.

Comment: Well, the primary part of the application will be running couchdb behind nginx - so I just need node.js to jump in at one point and do a http request, check the result, then forward the user on. I guess I could use PHP or Ruby for this - but I would rather stick with JavaScript. I also want the transaction over SSL.

Comment: I think using Nginx as a middleware for HTTP services would kill performance since it needs to start a new connection for every request. Erlang is also powerful to handle many concurrent connections.

Comment: Well, if couchdb could forward traffic to this single node.js page then that would be fine also - but a node.js server is still slower than nginx so I would rather stick with nginx when using two different backends (couchdb and node.js).